# grails show processing page while waiting for long action

Tags: jquery, grails, controller

I have a form that depending on the data input could take minutes to redirect to the success or failure actions.  I want to know how I can redirect to a "in progress" action that would tell them to allow up to 10 seconds * data entered for processing.

I would like to put some kind of spinner with the message on the screen while I'm waiting for my action to redirect to either success or failure.  Here is currently how my controller looks

```
def getdata() {

    def a = params.a
    def b = params.b
    def c = params.c
    def d = params.d
    def e = params.e

    GetData getData = new GetData(a:a, b:b, c:c)
    def results = getData(d,e)

    if (results == "success"){
        redirect(action: "success")
    }
    else{
        chain(action: "failure", model:[results:results])
    }
}
```

Comment: i would solve this on frontend side : let your getData() action return "success" or "failure" and make an ajax post to the action, and in js you do the redirect if status is success, so while ajax request is pending, you can show spinners or do elsewhat

Comment: @johnSmith so I want to make sure I'm understanding you right...  Make the form an ajax call instead of an action submit, and then let the ajax call return and do a redirect based on the results instead of doing it in the action?

Comment: yeah i think this is a simple solution, and while the ajax-call is pending you can hide/show/spin whatever you like. I think the serverside implementation would be very tricky compared to this